# React this.props.children versus createReactClass

Tags: reactjs, children, golden-layout

I have the following code that works:

```
    let registered = [];
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child) => {
        let name = child.type.name;
        if (registered.indexOf(name) === -1) {
            gLayout.registerComponent(name, createReactClass({
                render: () => (child)
            }));
            registered.push(name);
        }
    });
```

However, my question is if I can provide the child directly without wrapping it into a new react class.

I tried replacing the `createReactComponent` with render function, with simply `child.type` and `React.cloneElement(child, {})` but none of them work because the `registerComponent` function (of golden-layout framework) will complain that either a constructor function or the `componentWillUpdate` member function is missing.

Wrapping a new component around an existing component seems unnecessary overhead and may require me to duplicate code, so I'm looking for a cleaner option.